# Implement multi-containers pod design patterns in a single file possible?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

It's been taught that there are 3 patterns in multi-containers pod design.

- sidecar
- adapter
- ambassador

For separation concerns, is it possible to implement more than 1 pattern in pod design,

ie

can is it possible to have sidecar and adapter patterns implemented in a pod design ?

Or

it should strictly be encouraged to implement only 1 pattern in a pod design for a microservice app ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no restriction to implement only 1 pattern, it totally depends on your design/application requirements.

Each pattern has its own use-case. For e.g. if the application needs a side-car for logging purpose, needs adapter for modifying/converting data and needs a ambassador to provide external access, you can implement all of the patterns on a multi-container pod.

Comment: Hi Abdullah - thx for responding.